# Null Pointer Exception Occurs When Using FireBase Messaging

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently, I’ve got the error. The error occurs on Android oreo & pie devices. So, how to solve this problem.

> java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.write (Buffer.java:1182)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.read (Buffer.java:1221)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read
>   (RealBufferedSource.java:55)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read
>   (Http1xStream.java:393)   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.skipAll
>   (Util.java:159)   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.discard
>   (Util.java:141)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.close
>   (Http1xStream.java:410)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.close
>   (RealBufferedSource.java:396)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close
>   (RealBufferedSource.java:384)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzk.a (zzk.java:2) 
>   at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzj.close (zzj.java)   at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zza (zzd.java)   at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc
>   (FirebaseMessagingService.java)   at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.zze.run (zze.java:7)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (zza.java:7)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)